# Hive: creating flat table with hierarchy

Tags: sql, hive

I have a flat table with hierarchy:

```
+---------+--------+------------+
|  BOSS   |  NAME  |  BirthDate | 
+---------+--------+------------+
| 1       | Jack   | 2016-01-01 |
| 0       | John   | 2020-01-01 |
| 0       | Peter  | 2020-01-15 |
| 0       | Susan  | 2020-02-01 |
| 1       | Kate   | 2020-03-01 |
| 0       | Ann    | 2020-03-15 |
| 0       | Kris   | 2020-04-01 | 
+------+--------+---------------+
```

The meaning of the table is that Jack is the boss for John, Peter, Susan, while Kate is the boss for Ann and Kris, while everything is sorted by some other column, lets say BirthDate.

The question is:
how can I put boss's name into 4th column in this table, meaning:

```
+---------+--------+------------+-----------+
|  BOSS   |  NAME  |  BirthDate | BOSS NAME |
+---------+--------+------------+-----------+
| 1       | Jack   | 2016-01-01 | NULL      |
| 0       | John   | 2020-01-01 | Jack      |
| 0       | Peter  | 2020-01-15 | Jack      |
| 0       | Susan  | 2020-02-01 | Jack      |
| 1       | Kate   | 2020-03-01 | NULL      |
| 0       | Ann    | 2020-03-15 | Kate      |
| 0       | Kris   | 2020-04-01 | Kate      |
+------+--------+---------------+-----------+
```

I work with Hive, but if you give solution for some SQL database it could also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, you cannot do what you want because your table has no ordering column and your logic seems to depend on the ordering of the rows.

If you do have an ordering column, you can use window functions.  You can assign the "boss group" using a cumulative sum.  Then you can use cumulative conditional max or something similar within the group :

```
select t.*,
       (case when boss = 0
             then max(name) over (partition by boss_group)
        end) as boss_name
from (select t.*,
             sum(boss) over (order by <ordering col>) as boss_group
      from t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to determine the groupings. Grouping your data can be done by using a cumulative sum over your `boss` column.

Finally, you `left join` the table with the cumulative sum with itself to obtain boss name (The right table should only contain the boss names).

```
WITH grouped AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(boss) OVER(ORDER BY birthdate) AS group_number
    FROM your_table
)
SELECT
    a.boss,
    a.name,
    a.birthdate,
    b.name AS boss_name
FROM grouped AS a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, group_number FROM grouped WHERE boss = 1) AS b
ON a.group_number = b.group_number AND a.boss = 0;
```